# Не отправляет данные с формы на phpmyadmin(таблица)

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, form

```
 <?php
 require_once 'connection.php'; // подключаем скрипт

 // подключаемся к серверу
 $con = mysqli_connect(host, user, password, database);

 if ($con){
echo 'connect to server';
 }
 if(isset($_POST['reg']))
 {
 $login = $_POST['login'];

 $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO users (login) VALUES ('$login')";
}
?>

<form id = "form1" action="reg.php" method="post">

<input type="text" name="login">
<input type="submit" name = "reg">
</form>
```

связь с сервером есть, но данные с формы не записываются в базу.

Comment: `$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO users (login) VALUES ('$login')";` - а выполнить?

Comment: Не понял? Что выполнить?

Comment: Выполнить этот SQL-запрос.

Comment: По логике, после забивания input, он должен в базу данных добавлять закидывать login, а он не закидывает. Как отдельно его выполнить запрос?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Comment: Лучше уж на оригинал отправить http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php

Comment: mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (login) VALUES ('Glenn')"); Вот это выполнить запрос?

Comment: да, это выполнить запрос. Следующая остановка - параметризованные SQL-запросы в PHP.

Comment: После этого запроса данные всё равно не забиваются в таблицу((

Comment: как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: Захожу в phpmyadmin, там база в ней таблица, с одним столбцом(login), она пуста.

Comment: что возвращает `mysqli_query`?

Comment: @Nord275 коммент от `@Mr.D1rk - "Покажите структуру таблицы Users. Возможно в ней есть еще поля, которым обязательно нужно присвоить значения"

Comment: mysqli_query ничего не возвращает, когда забиваю input, форма просто очищается и данные улетают в никуда. В таблице кроме логин ничего нет 100%.

Comment: ну что-то она возвращает "For other successful queries it will return TRUE. FALSE on failure" `mysqli_error($con)`

Comment: Это надо проверку на успех запроса сделать через if?

Comment: да, и если `false`, выводить результат `mysqli_error($con)`

Comment: Голову сломал как сделать проверку через if) подскажите) вщ до этого проганье не изучал нормально

Answer (score 0):

Вы просто записали ваш запрос как стринг в переменную $sqlinsert. Теперь вам надо выполнить этот запрос

```
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "aidarkhanov", "", "adminpanel");
$connection->query("$sqlinsert");
```

Comment: Чёт не работает.